# Why doesn't this Canvas show up?

Tags: php, javascript, html, canvas

Can anyone tell me why this canvas won't show up? I just don't get it, it doesn't even display the

tag. I'm on crunchbang 10 using chromium. All other canvases work, but this one doesn't.

```
<!doctype html>  
<html lang="en">  
    <head>  
          <meta charset="utf-8">  
          <title>Test</title>  
          <meta name="description" content="An HTML5 Test">  
          <meta name="author" content="William Starkovich">  
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0">
          <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){

                //get a reference to the canvas
                var ctx = $('#canvas')[0].getContext("2d");

                //draw a circle
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(75, 75, 10, 0, Math.PI*2, true); 
                ctx.closePath();
                ctx.fill();
            }
          </script>    
    </head>  
    <body>  
         <canvas id="canvas" width="800px" height="100px">
        <p>Your browser doesn't support canvas.</p>
        </canvas>
    </body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is a syntax error in your JavaScript code.  You're missing a `);` on the closing `}` of the main function

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

            //get a reference to the canvas
            var ctx = $('#canvas')[0].getContext("2d");

            //draw a circle
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(75, 75, 10, 0, Math.PI*2, true); 
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fill();
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

There's an error in your JavaScript syntax:

```
        }) // you are missing this parenthesis
      </script>
```

Other than that the canvas absolutely shows up. Add:

`<canvas id="canvas" width="800px" height="100px" style="border: 1px solid black">`

To see a border around it.

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/RmVs4/8/